# c++ Binary search returns (found) no matter what user types

Tags: c++, binary-search, bubble-sort

I am working on a hangman game and I am trying to figure out why no matter what the user types it returns "That letter has already been used\n";

Here is the function definition...

```
bool binarySearch(char usedLetters[], int used, char letterToFind)
{

    bool found = false;
    int mid = 0, first = 0, last = used - 1;
    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        if (usedLetters[mid] == letterToFind)
            found = true;
        else if (usedLetters[mid] > letterToFind)   // works on ascending sorted collections only
            last = mid - 1;             // first half   
        else
            first = mid + 1;            // last half
    }
    if (found)
        return mid;
    return -1;
}
```

here is the declarations...

```
char gLetter;
int wrong = 0;
int gameStatus = 5;
int chances = 0;
int used = 0;
int letterIndex;
```

and here is the function call within main...

```
while (wrong != 6)                          // Function to find out which hangman board to print to user
{
    cout << "<<<<<<<<<< MAKE A GUESS >>>>>>>>>>\n";
    cout << "Guessed Letters: " << usedLetters << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> gLetter;
    gLetter = toupper(gLetter);

    usedLetters[used++] = gLetter;

    letterIndex = binarySearch(usedLetters, used, gLetter);     // Binary search for letters used

    bubbleSort(usedLetters, used);

    if (letterIndex == -1)
    {
        continue;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "That letter has already been used\n";
    }
```

Just need to figure out why the characters that the user enters are always being found when they haven't been used yet.I think it is because I declared "int used = 0" but when I change it to something else, like 26, the binary search doesn't return any letters.

Comment: Be careful, usedLetters does not have pre-allocated memory, and C++ is very dumb when it comes to that: it just writes past the end of the array. (Or at least, I don't see how you're allocating it, but [used++] makes me nervous.

Comment: Also, your binaryserach implementation has an overflow issue: `mid = (first + last) / 2` should be `mid = first + (last-first) / 2`

Comment: You are returning `int mid,-1` from `bool` type function.

Comment: The array needs to be sorted *before* you do the binary search.

Comment: Also, for making sure that only unique letters are entered you could use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead.

Comment: When casting ints to bools, -1 is cast to true, as is anything else except for 0.

Comment: The used++ is making sure that when the gLetter is entered into the usedLetters array that it doesn't overide the other letter inside but instead adds on to the array. and I tried the

Answer (score 4):

`false` is 0. Anything else is `true`.

```
bool binarySearch(char usedLetters[], int used, char letterToFind)
...
    if (found)
        return mid;
    return -1;
```

Will only return `false` if you found something at index zero (`mid` is 0).

See also http://ideone.com/2XU2bn

--edit--

You indicated you only want to know if the letter is present, so just return `found`

Comment: I'm confused on how I would fix that would I need to change the value of used so that first still remains less than last ( first < = last) and if so what value?

Comment: @GregoryKinsey What are you trying to return? Whether the letter was found or what position it was found at? If you want to return whether it was found, just return found. If you want to return the position, change the return type to int.

Comment: So the letters entered by the user should all be placed into the usedLetters array. So if the user enters A that A should be placed into that array and this binarySearch is trying to find whether or not that A has already been entered by the user. So if the user enters A a second time the program should return "That letter has already been used". The problem is that no matter what letter the user enters it always returns "That letter has already been used" instead of just continuing on with the game.

Comment: So it sounds like you don't care where the letter is, only if it is in the array or not. In that case do as kfsone said and just return found. since it is already a bool representing whether the letter is in the array or not